# Golang (Gopls) throws incompatibleAssign even if the expected type is correct

Tags: go, gopls

I am passing `timeout` declared as `time.Duration` to `context.withTimeout`. It should work, but I still get `incompatibleAssign` error. Any idea?
Why I am getting this error

```
var timeout time.Duration
cannot use timeout (variable of type time.Duration) as time.Duration 
value in argument to context.WithTimeout
```

**Code:**

```golang
timeout := time.Duration(30 * time.Second)
ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
defer cancelFn()
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHAos.png)

Comment: `time.Duration` returns an int64, however `context.WithTimeout` require a `time.Duration` type as the second argument.

Comment: This smells like two different `time` packages. Make sure the `context` package imports the same `time` package as the one in which you are getting the error. And make sure the package versions are the same as well.

Comment: @EndreSimo `time.Duration` is a type, it doesn't return anything. Hence `time.Duration(30*time.Second)` is a conversion but I doubt the result of that expression is `int64`, besides there's no mention of `int64` in the error.

Comment: @blackgreen yes it runs and builds successfully. But shows a red flag in VS Code. Seems to be `gopls` related issue.

Comment: @blackgreen It suddenly started showing up this issue. Till yesterday it was working well. I am sure there have been no configuration changes for quite some time.

Comment: Gopls sometimes stops working for me, and will show errors that have been fixed already. Force closing VSCode and reopening fixes it for me. I assume because GoPls is bound to the VSCode instance and is restarted when reopening.